# How to show alertdialog when progress bar is full

Tags: android, button, textview, progress-bar

I have two textviews and one button. I would like to add the count to the first text view when repeatedly clicked or until the progress bar is complete and double-click the value to add the counter to the second textview.

I have wrote the code for the first part but I have problems for the second part when it completes the progress-bar for the first textview. Dialogs are looped and not working properly.

Please guide me on what I should do or tell me if you know the doc. Thankful
Or How to kill thread when progress = 100 Or how to stop the handler?

//code for button:

```
TimerGameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        if (progressStatus < 100){

          soccerA();

        }
        if (progressStatus == 100){
          soccerB();
        }


      }
    });
```

// soccerA method:

```
public void soccerA() {

    NameACounter++;
    txtNameACounter.setText(Integer.toString(NameACounter));
    progressStatus = 0;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        while (progressStatus < 100) {
          progressStatus += 1;

          try {
            Thread.sleep(600);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

          handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              TimerGameButton.setProgress(progressStatus);

              tv.setText("next");
              // If task execution completed
              if (progressStatus == 100) {

                // Set a message of completion
                tv.setText("time over!");

                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(StartLowGame.this);
                builder1.setMessage("Write your message here.");
                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                  "Yes",
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                      soccerB();

                    }
                  });

                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();


              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }).start(); 
  }
```

// soccerB method:

```
public void soccerB() {

    NameBCounter++;
    txtNameBCounter.setText(Integer.toString(NameBCounter));
    progressStatus = 0;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        while (progressStatus < 100) {
          progressStatus += 1;

          try {
            Thread.sleep(600);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

          handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              TimerGameButton.setProgress(progressStatus);

              tv.setText("next");
              // If task execution completed
              if (progressStatus == 100) {

                // Set a message of completion
                tv.setText("time over!");

                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(StartLowGame.this);
                builder1.setMessage("Write your message here.");
                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                  "Yes",
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();

                    }
                  });

                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();


              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }).start(); 
  }
```

Comment: why you are creating threads in method? and which textview is this  tv.setText("next");

Comment: @Muazzamabbas This is just a name to test

Comment: How to kill thread when progress = 100 and come out from block?

Answer (score 0):

@Amir Bakhtiari change your scoreA method to

```
public void soccerA() {

        NameACounter++;
        txtNameACounter.setText(Integer.toString(NameACounter));
        progressStatus = 0;

        while (progressStatus < 100) {
            progressStatus += 1;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(600);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            TimerGameButton.setProgress(progressStatus);

            tv.setText("next");
            // If task execution completed
            if (progressStatus == 100) {

                // Set a message of completion
                tv.setText("time over!");

                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(StartLowGame.this);
                builder1.setMessage("Write your message here.");
                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                        "Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                soccerB();

                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();

            }

        }
    }
```

And change ScoreB method to as:

```
 public void soccerB () {

            NameBCounter++;
            txtNameBCounter.setText(Integer.toString(NameBCounter));
            progressStatus = 0;

            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus += 1;

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(600);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                TimerGameButton.setProgress(progressStatus);

                tv.setText("next");
                // If task execution completed
                if (progressStatus == 100) {

                    // Set a message of completion
                    tv.setText("time over!");

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(StartLowGame.this);
                    builder1.setMessage("Write your message here.");
                    builder1.setCancelable(true);

                    builder1.setPositiveButton(
                            "Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                    alert11.show();


                }
            }


        }
```

The reason why your dialog are looped and not working because you are creating new thread each time when click on a button.